# How Can I Fade the Blur effect? [CSS, HTML]

Tags: css, background, blur, fade

On my website, I got a blured border around my images as seen:

[image of my current progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB6NK.png)

Is there any way that i can FADE the blur effect? So at the edge of the border, the effect is very subtle, but closer to the image, the effect is very strong?

Current code:

```css
.block {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: your question is incomplete

Comment: please clarify what you mean. What do you not understand about this Question? :)

Comment: Try `filter: blur(10px)` Reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp

Comment: you did not explain how your effect should evolve

Comment: "So at the edge of the border, the effect is very subtle, but closer to the image, the effect is very strong" Imagine a combination between the "backdrop-filter: blur();" and the "linear-gradient" effect, where the blur is a gradient from very blurry to 0 blur.

Comment: that doesn't explain the process

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76529605/22066054) answers your question. Only works on Firefox though.